# What is the word to mean to apply attributes of an entire race to a single individual?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, synonyms

Normally *racism* is used to mean generalizing about an entire race based on a few individual examples, but what is the word to mean to apply attributes of an entire race to a single individual? That is often referred to as *racism* as well, but I believe they are distinct and would like a more precise word or term. I know the terms for the logical fallacies associated with it, but am seeking a general English term.

For example, three nurples bit me, therefore all nurples are biters. This is a case of an [overgeneralization](http://www.nizkor.org/features/fallacies/hasty-generalization.html).

This is the term I'm looking for: Most nurples are savants. Aijan is a nurple. Therefore Aijan is a savant. This is a case of [fallacy of division](http://www.nizkor.org/features/fallacies/division.html).

Is there a more plain word to express the second example, carrying the connotation of *racism*, but not the word *racism* proper?

Comment: What nurples in this context?

Comment: If you "apply attributes of an entire race to a single individual", is that not just a special case of "generalizing about an entire race", just with one individual being the focus of that generalisation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Where racism is a move from specific to general, **discrimination** is a move from the more general to the more specific.

*[discrimination](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/discrimination)* 3. Treatment or consideration based on class or category rather than individual merit; partiality or prejudice

This means that prejudices held by an individual towards a group are transferred onto a single individual without regards to his individual merits.  Of course, discrimination has a more general sense (as does racism) but according to your dichotomy, it fits the movement from general prejudice to individual prejudice.

Comment: discrimination does imply a negative. "he is asian so good at maths" or "of course he is a great lover - he's Belgian" are stereotypes but not necessarily discrimination

Comment: i love your second example....Belgians needs a stereotype (positive or negative) they can cling on to  :D :D

Answer (score 41):

You are looking for:

[***stereotype***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stereotype) : 4. (Sociology) A set of inaccurate, simplistic generalizations about a group that allows others to categorize them and treat them accordingly

In your case it would be *racial stereotyping*.

Comment: I believe this is a case of [overgeneralization](http://www.nizkor.org/features/fallacies/hasty-generalization.html)